# how to pick the lowest item in nested relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a  Hotel model and a room model and room prices model here i want to query through my nested relationship to find the cheapest room so i have to get all prices for a room in todays time and sort them pick the lowest for each room and after that pick the lowest room for my result :

here in my model relation ship i pick the lowest price between all prices for each room :

```
// this will bring me the lowest price for the room in the day
public function roomPricingHistorySearch()
{
    return $this->hasOne(roomprices::class,'room_id','id')->orderBy('sales_price','ASC');
}
```

here i want to pick the lowest between all rooms

```
$data = Hotel::with([
    'rooms.roomprices' => function ($query) {
        //here i want to pick the lowest price room of all.
        $query->Where('is_deleted', '1');
    }
]);
```

Comment: Where is the sort by on the roomprices query? (the latter query)? Also, `$query->where...`, no capital letter

Answer (score 1):

If you sorted the rooms on price, then get the first one in the collection. That will be the cheapest one

Code sample

```
$product->ticketTypes()->hasActivePrices()->orderBy('price')‌​->first()
```

This will result in a collection orderd by the price, the lowest one will be the first one. Thats why we do first()

```
$data = Hotel::with([
    'rooms.roomprices' => function ($query) {

        $query->orderBy('sales_prices', 'ASC')->limit(1); // try this
    }
]);
``
```

Comment: no i have not sorted the rooms with price as its a nested relation its not the rooms object to be sorted and take the first its the price object so i want to compare prices of all rooms and pick the lowest